# Countdown timer not starting at the given value

Tags: python, pygame

this is my game play function with the main loop. The issue is that my timer with the inclusion of `clock.tick(60)` counts down from 100 (the assigned value) but at a pace slower than seconds (about 2 seconds). Without `clock.tick(60)` the countdown starts at 100 then immediately jumps to 97 then continues at a pace of just a little longer than seconds. All i'm aware of is that apart from clock.tick(60), `milliseconds += clock.tick(60)` has an effect aswell. is there a way to ensure the countdown starts at 100 and has second intervals without negatively effecting the much needed fps? If any more code such is needed then i'm happy to submit it.

Note: I've removed some unnecessary details for this post hence the seemingly unused global variables

```
def Gameplay():
    global P1_sped
    global P1_speed
    global P2_sped
    global P2_speed
    global Touch
    global player1_Lives
    global player2_Lives
    global P1_score
    global P2_score
    global done
    
    Player_1_turn = True
    Player_2_turn = False
    P1_Turns = 3
    P2_Turns = 3

    resetTimer = 100
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    seconds = 100
    milliseconds = 0


    
    P1_sped = P1_sped + 1
    P1_speed = P1_speed - 1
    print(P1_sped, "sped")
    print(P1_speed, "speed")
    Countdown = True
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
                
            # Keydown movement bindings
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    P2.changespeed(P2_speed, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    P2.changespeed(P2_sped, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    P2.changespeed(0, P2_speed)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    P2.changespeed(0, P2_sped)
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    P1.changespeed(P1_speed, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    P1.changespeed(P1_sped, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    P1.changespeed(0, P1_speed)
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    P1.changespeed(0, P1_sped)
                    
            # Keyup movement bindings          
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    P2.changespeed(P2_sped, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    P2.changespeed(P2_speed, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    P2.changespeed(0, P2_sped)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    P2.changespeed(0, P2_speed)
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    P1.changespeed(P1_sped, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    P1.changespeed(P1_speed, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    P1.changespeed(0, P1_sped)
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    P1.changespeed(0, P1_speed)
        

        #milliseconds += clock.tick_busy_loop(60) #returns the time since the last time we called the function, and limits the frame rate to 60FPS
        milliseconds += clock.tick(60)
                    
      

        #  Applying an update to the sprites
        all_sprite_list.update()

        #  Backgorund colour
        screen.fill(D_BLUE)

        #  Applying the sprites
        all_sprite_list.draw(screen)

        #  The countdown used before the game starts
        if Countdown == True:
        
            screen.blit(THREE, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2-53.5,SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-91.5))
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            screen.fill(D_BLUE)
            all_sprite_list.draw(screen)
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK,(SCREEN_WIDTH/2-250,SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-250,500,500))

            screen.blit(TWO, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2-52,SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-88.5))
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            screen.fill(D_BLUE)
            all_sprite_list.draw(screen)
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK,(SCREEN_WIDTH/2-250,SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-250,500,500))

            screen.blit(ONE, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2-39,SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-87))
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(1)

            Countdown = False
            
        if milliseconds > 1000:
            seconds -= 1
            milliseconds -= 1000
        if seconds == 0:
            #Countdown = True
            P1.reset(500, 500)
            P2.reset(800, 500)
            if Player_1_turn:
                P1_score += 1000
                P1_Turns -= 1
                Countdown = True
                seconds = resetTimer
                if P1_Turns == 0:
                    Text("GameOver Player1", 100, WHITE, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-350)
                    pygame.display.update()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    Player_2_turn = True
                    Player_1_turn = False
            else:
            #if Player_2_turn == True or Player_1_turn == False:
                P2_score += 1000
                P2_Turns -= 1
                Countdown = True
                seconds = resetTimer
                if P2_Turns == 0:
                    Text("GameOver Player2", 100, WHITE, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-350)
                    pygame.display.update()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    #GameEnd()
                    CharSel()
        #print(P1_score, "P1 score")
        #print(P2_score, "P2 score")
                

        Text(seconds, 100, WHITE, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-350)
     
        pygame.display.flip()
        #  Used for fps
        clock.tick(60)
        
StartScreen()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `clock.tick(60)` twice in your main loop. Once where you do `milliseconds += clock.tick(60)` and once at the end of the loop. If you read the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick), you will see this '***This method should be called once per frame. It will compute how many milliseconds have passed since the previous call. If you pass the optional framerate argument the function will delay to keep the game running slower than the given ticks per second***'.

So if you call it twice per loop the effect will be to have the loop execute at half the expected frame rate. Since you are calling it with 60, that means that you frame rate is actually going to be 30 frames per second.

Also, the return is the amount of time since the last time it was called. Since you call it twice, the call at the top of the loop will return the time since the call at the bottom of the loop, not since the last call from the top of the loop. So it is only going to be counting about half the time in your game loop, which accounts for why you are trying to count 1 second worth but 2 seconds are elapsing.

You need to remove one of the two calls to `clock.tick(60)`

EDIT:

You have the `Countdown == True` section that uses up 3 seconds on initial startup. That countdown takes place between the first `milliseconds += clock.tick(60)` and the following `clock.tick(60)`. Those 3 seconds get returned and then hidden by the `clock.tick(60)`, whereas without that they will be returned as 3000 ms to the `milliseconds += clock.tick(60)` and so cause the time displayed to quickly drop down by those 3 seconds.

You could probably hide that time loss by adding a `clock.tick()` right after the `Countdown = False` inside the `if Countdown == True` block.

Comment: I understand this although I suppose I should have been more specific. When I remove clock.tick(60) at the end of the loop the timer then works in seconds (or at least really closely to seconds which is great) but the countdown then starts at 97 if the desired value is 100/ always 3 to 5 less than the assigned value

Comment: @Jae I have added an edit to the answer to explain the time loss described in the above comment.